# Facebook interferes with my login ID, how do I stop it?

Tags: login, facebook

My wife and I have Facebook ID's which only differ by two letters (our initials). If I log off and try to log in with her ID, Facebook 'helpfully' jumps in and tells me I've made a small typo and they have generously corrected it for me.

I have not made a typo and can't figure out how to stop Facebook from doing this.  It totally prevents my wife from logging on to Facebook using the larger screen on my desktop system.

There must be a way to tell Facebook to keep it's fingers out of the process.

It is **not** Autofill, or LastPass or anything like that it is **Facebook**. See the attached picture.

[image: Facebook being "Helpful"]

Comment: Questions about Facebook are not on topic here at Superuser.  I suggest clicking "not you" in order to sign into the correct account though, I also suggest chanigng your Facebook email to something more like `gd.****@gmail.com` instead of `gd****@gmail.com`

Comment: Are you absolutely certain this is a facebook problem and not a problem with your web browser? Many web browsers will autocomplete and you have to click "Escape" to stop them.

Comment: @Mokubai - There are existing questions here at Superuser which describe a similar problem.  I can confirm Facebook will attempt to do what is describe in the question.

Comment: My best suggestion would be for you not to share a browser. Either use separate browser profiles, or, better, completely different browsers. Even better, use different user accounts on Windows.

Comment: Try with other browser and see what is happening!